# Working add_action for after new package created wordpress download manager plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am using wordpress download manager and now i want to send email to wordpress users. Everything is fine but I don't know to select the add_action.

I found two add_action references:

1. create_package_frontend
2. after_add_package

These two are not working for me.

If anyone have ideas to "send email to wordpress users when a new file is been added in download manager plugin"

The plugin link is www.wpdownloadmanager.com

I added these codes in php file

```
function notify_admin($package_id, $package){

     $edit = "<a href='".get_edit_post_link( $package_id)."'>Edit Package</a><br/>"; 
     $view = "<a href='".get_permalink( $package_id )."'>Edit Package</a><br/>";
     $message = "Package Title: {$package->post_title}<br/>{$view}<br/>{$edit}";
     wp_mail(get_option("admin_email"), "New Package Added", $message, "From: no-reply@sitename\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n"); 
}

add_action("after_add_package", "notify_admin");
```

Comment: hows your tried with `after_add_package` hook? show your code

Comment: I added the code in my question @jogesh_pi.

Comment: If it's not about mail function, make a logging report into function too see if the function fires anyhow?